# Underline in HTML not disappearing

Tags: html, css

So recently, I've started to build my own website to show off work as a portfolio but in CSS when I do text-decoration: none; nothing happens. Everything else seems to work just fine when using CSS just not the nav bar.

My [HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/LunarsDesigns/j34n4qad/):

```css
#nav {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
}

#nav li {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: dimgrey;
}

#nav li:active {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  color: white;
}

#nav li:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color:
}

#nav li:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1>HomePage</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6hbdqszs/1/, text-decoration should be applied to the anchor. see jsfiddle above.

Answer (score 6):

The `text-decoration` is applied to the `<a>` tags, not the `<li>` tags.

---

**To elaborate:** Usually, in these kind of list item menus, the list items (the `<li>` tags) are used to form the *general structure* and *position* of the links .

Everything related to styling and interaction with the *links themselves*, such as font colors and hover effects, are to be applied to the links - the `<a>` tags. (There are a few exceptions, as always)

In your CSS, `float` and `list-style` are the only declarations needed to position your links:

```
#nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
```

It would make more sense, at least to me, to apply the rest of the rulesets to the `<a>` elements:

```css
#nav {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: dimgrey;
}

#nav a:active {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  color: white;
}

#nav a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color:
}

#nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1>HomePage</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

The underline is for the `a` tag, not for `li`. Add the following lines and the underline will go away:

```
#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `text-decoration` for the `<a>` elements, rather than the `<li>` elements.

See this example:

```css
#nav {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
}

#nav li {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: dimgrey;
}

#nav li:active {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  color: white;
}

#nav li:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color:
}

#nav li:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: grey;
}

#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1>HomePage</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```